# While mapping an array of objects to React Elements, one of the properties disappears

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, frontend, react-dom

I'm trying to make a React app to fetch data from the pokemon api (https://pokeapi.co/docs/v2#pokemon) and display it in a grid.

My component tree:

App -> Pokedex -> n(PokeCard -> PokeAvatar)

In the App component, I fetch the pokemon data, I get the 20 first results and map the resulting array to one where the URL of each Pokemon is also fetched (each Object inside of the Array has a 'name', 'url', and 'info' property). The info property holds all the data from each individual fetch.

After rendering the Pokedex with this array as props, in the Pokedex component I map the array to an array of elements containing only the data I want to display (name, and a few properties from the 'info' property).

Here's the code that raises the error:

```js
export class Pokedex extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log("this.props.pokeArray:", this.props.pokeArray); // shows pokemons with the 3 properties
    const elements = this.props.pokeArray.map((pokemon, i) => {
      console.log(pokemon); // logs the pokemon without the info property
      return (
        <PokeCard
          key={`poke${i}`}
          id={pokemon.info.id} //error raised here: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
          name={pokemon.name}
          types={pokemon.info.types}
          sprite={pokemon.info.sprites["front_default"]}
        />
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="pkdx-pokedex-container">
        <h1>Pokedex</h1>
        {elements}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's also the code from its parent element, App:

```js
import "./App.css";
import { Pokedex } from "./components/Pokedex/Pokedex";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from "react-query-devtools";

// *** Base API url

const url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon";

// *** Async, because we need to have the data before second fetch

async function fetchPokemon() {
  const response = await fetch(url);

  const data = (await response.json()).results;

  // *** Keep url of fetch and add new info property to each pokemon

  data.forEach(async (poke) => {
    const res = await fetch(poke.url);
    poke.info = await res.json();
  });

  return data;
}

function App() {
  const info = useQuery("fetchPokemon", fetchPokemon);

  if (info.status === "success") {
    console.log("pokeArray:", info.data); // each Pokemon has the three properties
    return (
      <div>
        <Pokedex pokeArray={info.data} />;
        <ReactQueryDevtools />
      </div>
    );
  } else return null;
}

export default App;
```

I don't know if I'm missing something, but I don't understand why it doesn't show the 'info' property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here lies within `fetchPokemon`. When using `await fetch(poke.url)` within the `forEach` callback the callback will happily await the response. However `forEach` does not handle the promise returned by the callback. Meaning that the `pokemon.info` attribute is set some time after the `data` is returned from the `fetchPokemon` function.

To solve this use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to store the resulting promises, then [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to await for a list of promises to resolve.

```
async function fetchPokemon() {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = (await response.json()).results;

  await Promise.all(data.map(async (pokemon) => {
    const res = await fetch(pokemon.url);
    pokemon.info = await res.json();
  }));

  return data;
}
```

An async function always returns a promise, so passing a async function to `map()` will map the current array elements to promises. This array can then be passed to `Promise.all()` which will wait for all promises to finish. The promises will all resolve to `undefined` because there is no return value within the `map()` callbacks, however the data is stored within `data` so we can return that instead.

```js
const url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon";

async function fetchPokemon() {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = (await response.json()).results;

  await Promise.all(data.map(async (pokemon) => {
    const res = await fetch(pokemon.url);
    pokemon.info = await res.json();
  }));

  return data;
}


fetchPokemon().then(pokemon => {
  document.body.textContent = JSON.stringify(pokemon);
});
```

Comment: hey! Thank you so much for the quick response.

I've just tried your solution and it works, but I still don't get why: 

In the Pokedex component, the array from the props does have the info property set, so when feeding it to the map function it *should* display it, but inside the function the info property is lost.

That's what seems weird :\

Comment: @areberuto `forEach` doesn't do anything with the promise returned by the async function passed as callback. Meaning that the callback does wait, but the `fetchPokemon` function does not. It will move on to the next statement which is `return data` before the `info` properties are set.

Comment: hmmm, I will look it up more thoroughly. Thank you for taking the time!

Comment: @areberuto See also [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: 3limin4t0r, thank you for the post example! I can see what you mean there, and going through the MDN docs I've read that forEach expects a synchronous callback, so using an async callback will tend to cause problems.

I still wonder why the props of my child component display the answer with the promises resolved, though.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are doing an async `forEach` and not awaiting it.  You may want to change to a `map` and do a `const data = await Promise.all(data.map(...))` to ensure your data has loaded.

I put together a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-mclaren-8pm52?file=/src/App.js).  Check it out:

```
import React from "react";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from "react-query-devtools";

export class Pokedex extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log("this.props.pokeArray:", this.props.pokeArray); // shows pokemons with the 3 properties
    const elements = this.props.pokeArray.map((pokemon, i) => {
      console.log("POKEMON", pokemon); // logs the pokemon without the info property
      return (
        <React.Fragment key={i}>
          <div>key={`poke${i}`}</div>
          <div>id={pokemon.info.id}</div>
          <div>name={pokemon.name}</div>
          <div>sprite={pokemon.info.sprites["front_default"]}</div>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="pkdx-pokedex-container">
        <h1>Pokedex</h1>
        {elements}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// *** Base API url

const url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon";

// *** Async, because we need to have the data before second fetch

async function fetchPokemon() {
  const response = await fetch(url);

  const data = (await response.json()).results;

  // *** Keep url of fetch and add new info property to each pokemon

  const x = await Promise.all(
    data.map(async (poke) => {
      const res = await fetch(poke.url);
      return {
        ...poke,
        info: await res.json()
      };
    })
  );

  return x;
}

function App() {
  const info = useQuery("fetchPokemon", fetchPokemon);

  if (info.status === "success") {
    console.log("pokeArray:", info.data); // each Pokemon has the three properties
    return (
      <div>
        <Pokedex pokeArray={info.data} />;
        <ReactQueryDevtools />
      </div>
    );
  } else return null;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: hey! Thank you so much for the quick response.

I've just tried your solution and it works, but I still don't get why: 

In the Pokedex component, the array from the props does have the info property set, so when feeding it to the map function it *should* display it, but inside the function the info property is lost.

That's what seems weird :\

Comment: It is because the data has not finished loading yet.  You have an `async` function in your `forEach` which is not awaited, hence the code continues before the values have been resolved.  Consequently, you are trying to render with data that hasn't loaded yet.

Comment: hmmm, I will look it up more thoroughly. Thank you for taking the time!